# Jackson is changing date to one day old in spring boot rest application.

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have created a simple application with spring boot 1.5.2. I am passing date and already mentioned the date format in application.properties file as follwoing : 
spring.jackson.joda-date-time-format=yyyy-MM-dd

But while calling the rest rest service using any client for POST(Insert) or PUT(Update), date is changing to on day old. Example 2017-03-21 will change to 2017-03-20.

Comment: How are you entity date properties mapped? What type are they? Are you using a `@Type`? Too little information to help you.

Comment: Are the server & client are located at the same timzone?

Comment: This is a timezone issue. Jackson converts your date (which is by default to the local timezone) to another timezone. The only way I found to fix this issue is with a ZonedDateTime set to UTC.

Comment: Hello Sundararj, Yes Server & Client are located at the same timezone.

Comment: Hello Guillaume, How I can change the timezone to UTC I tried to fix it by changing following property in application.property file :  spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=false

Comment: Hello Gregg, Not I am not using @Type . I am using Date type

Comment: I just fixed it by changing date to LocalDate in my model (Repository) and created a new class which will convert LocalDate to Date & Date to LocalDate for database Insertion by implementing AttributeConverter. Also used @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class) and @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class) on my getter and setter methods respectively. Thank you Every one for help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I solved it in that way:
In your entitiy, add theses annotations:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, locale = "fr-FR", timezone = "Europe/Paris")
private Date yourDate;
```

Or you can add theses line to application.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=Europe/Paris
spring.jackson.locale=fr_FR
```

If you are in another country you can change locale and timezone, but even if you keep France, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the timezone to UTC like below

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

It solved my problem.